# Excel Macro: If Cell A is clicked, copy Cell B and paste as value, then return position to Cell A

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am creating a form template in Excel that has Cell B = TODAY() so, when a user opens the template to fill out the form, today's date is displayed.

However, once the user fills out the form, I would like Cell B to equal the value of TODAY(), so the cell does not update every time the Workbook is opened.

My solution to this was to create a Macro that does the following:

When the user clicks on Cell A, a cell that the user is required to fill in with text, Cell B, containing the formula =TODAY(), is copied and pasted as a value to the same position.  Then, Cell A is selected again so the user can fill in the required information.

Below is my example VBA, which checks if Cell A is empty instead of being clicked on.  I would like to change this though, if someone could help with that.

In this example, Cell A is E11 and Cell B is E13.

```
Sub Date_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Sheets("Form").Range("E13")
    If Sheets("Form").Range("E11") = Empty Then
        Sheets("Form").Range("E13") = TODAY()
    Else
        Rng.Copy
        Rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Set Rng = Nothing
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Cells(11, 5).Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: would it make more sense to execute the macro on save of document?  And why not record a macro that does exactly what you want and save it as the needed code?

Comment: How could I execute a macro on save?  That might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the workbook object you have a built in event workbook_beforesave...
you could put the code there.

I recorded a macro which updates B3 to be a hard value, eliminating the formula.

I then copied the code out of the macro and hit save.  You may need to update the "range" to account for specific worksheet if multiple sheets in workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: This works but I face the problem of saving the template now.  I would like the .xltm template to have =TODAY() in the cell when it is saved and, upon opening the template into a new .xlsm, editing any needed text, then saving the document with the macro running.

Comment: Nevermind, I just set it to execute on Workbook_Open, so when the .xltm opens into a new, unsaved .xlsm, the date is pasted as a value and can never update again.  Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

How's this (this goes in the worksheet you want to run it on's module):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cellA As Range, cellB As Range
Set cellA = Sheets("Form").Range("E11")
Set cellB = Sheets("Form").Range("E13")
    If Target.Row = cellA.Row And Target.Column = cellA.Column Then
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = cellA
    If cellA = Empty Then
        cellB.Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(Month(Now()) & "/" & Day(Now()) & "/" & Year(Now()), "MM/DD/YYYY")
    Else
        Rng.Copy
        Rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Set Rng = Nothing
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Cells(11, 5).Select
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You may need to check my declarations, but that should get you going. It'll check to see if cell E11 was selected, and if so, will run.